# Global Secondary Index To an Existing Table

Tags: indexing, amazon-dynamodb

I have created `DynamoDB` table:

```
[
    'AttributeDefinitions' => [
        [
            'AttributeName' => 'UserId',
            'AttributeType' => 'N',
        ],
        [
            'AttributeName' => 'Created',
            'AttributeType' => 'S',
        ],
    ],
    'KeySchema' => [
        [
            'AttributeName' => 'UserId',
            'KeyType' => 'HASH',
        ],
        [
            'AttributeName' => 'Created',
            'KeyType' => 'RANGE',
        ],
    ],
    'ProvisionedThroughput' => [
        'ReadCapacityUnits' => 5,
        'WriteCapacityUnits' => 5,
    ],
    'TableName' => 'Images',
]
```

Adding a data, `TargetUserIdUserId` field is added as well. How do I set GSI for three columns (UserId, TragetUserId, Created)? Or maybe I need to modify table `KeySchema`?

Looks like I cannot do it using AWS Console (only two keys are available):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DynamoDB key can be made of one attribute (partition key) or two attributes (partition key and range key).

You should create a new attribute which combines UserId + TargetUserIdUserId and make this the GSI partition key, then make Created the range key.

Comment: How do I create new attribute which combines UserId + TargetUserIdUserId?

Comment: So if your UserId attribute was A and your TargetUserIdUserId was 1 your SomeNewAttribute would be A1. If its an existing table with data, you will need a script to go through and create the attribute on each item.